# How can I add chrome web emulator to vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want to use chrome web emulator but I can't do it with n hot restart in shortcut.

Only when i type this entry from terminal i can view chrome web emulator;

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

I want instant update of the chrome web emulator I use with hot restart or ctrl+s.

I was able to do this before but after the dart and flutter update I can't.
Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the folder name and it will work change it to

```
quiz_app
```